# Unfinished transaction remaining in Fedora 17 software update

Tags: fedora

When I doing the software update on Fedora 17, I get this message prompt to me:

```
There are unfinished transactions remaining. Please run yum-complete-transaction as root.
```

I follow the instruction and I get this error:

```
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
** Found 9 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
32:bind-libs-9.9.2-7.P2.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-libs-9.9.2-5.P1.fc17.x86_64
32:bind-license-9.9.2-7.P2.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with 32:bind-license-9.9.2-5.P1.fc17.noarch
firefox-19.0.2-1.fc17.x86_64 has installed conflicts xulrunner(x86-64) > ('0', '19.1', None): xulrunner-20.0-1.fc17.x86_64
1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.17-2.3.8.3.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.8.0.fc17.x86_64
libipa_hbac-1.9.4-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with libipa_hbac-1.8.6-1.fc17.x86_64
sssd-1.9.4-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with sssd-1.8.6-1.fc17.x86_64
sssd-client-1.9.4-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with sssd-client-1.8.6-1.fc17.x86_64
tzdata-java-2013b-2.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with tzdata-java-2013b-1.fc17.noarch
xulrunner-20.0-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with xulrunner-19.0.2-1.fc17.x86_64
```

How could resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `yum-utils` package, and run `package-cleanup --cleandupes` (check the manual pages for other options), then try again. You might need to update `yum` and possibly `rpm` beforehand.

Comment: This works great. Some add-on, after this command, I still need to issue `yum-complete-transaction` command to resume my updates.